# Keeping CMD open while using Xamarin Studios on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, xamarin-studio

What I'm asking is how to keep the cmd up while writing code in .Net c#, we used the terminal often to display our results. But when I hit the play button on Windows it pops the cmd windows up but instantly closes it. I need this to stay open to see how my code is doing.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but if you're talking about a console application, why not add a `Console.ReadKey()` to the end of your application so it won't close until you press a key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the `Project Options` and go the `Run / General` and select "Pause console output". It is only going to open when you run/debug your code. The console window will not auto-close now but will when you press any key with it selected...

[image]